# How does this c++ structure work and how can i use it?

Tags: c++

I have to use the next interface for a project but i don't know how to initialize the object of class PriorityQueue, or how even to use the Relation type...Could someone explain it to me please?
Thank you!

```cpp
typedef int TElem;
typedef int TPriority;

typedef std::pair<TElem, TPriority> Element;

typedef bool(*Relation)(TPriority , TPriority);

class PriorityQueue {
    PriorityQueue(Relation r);
}
```

Comment: Look at the documentation that whoever developed this has written.

Comment: My Teacher does not have any documentation she just throw this kind of thing at us without explaining it. We have to find on our own how to use it....

Comment: @GagiuFilip unfortunately I know there can be such teachers. However you are not only entitled, but even have the duty for yourself to demand (in a polite way of course) for relevant explanations from your teacher. His job is to teach you and your job is to learn. If any of the two parties don't do their job then you are just wasting time. At the end of the day your teacher gets his/her salary but you are the one who has high stakes in the game. Fight for your right to education.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like first to convert `typedef` with `using`. It will make things a little more clear:

```
using TElem = int;
using TPriority = int;

using Element = std::pair<TElem, TPriority>;

using Relation = bool(*)(TPriority , TPriority);

class PriorityQueue
{
public:
    PriorityQueue(Relation r);
};

bool some_relation(TPriority, TPriority);

auto test()
{
    auto pq = PriorityQueue(some_relation);

}
```

As you can see `Relation` is nothing more than a type alias for a pointer to a function taking two `int` parameters and returning `bool`.

Most likely the `Relation` function is used to determine which of two `priorities` is higher. However it needs to be documented. E.g. it should return `true` if first argument has higher priority or if the second arg has higher priority? What about if both arg have the same priority? These kind of things can only be known from documentation.